# How to deactivate css preprocessing in grails 2.2?

Tags: css, grails

After adding these lines into my style.css file I don't get the expected return in frontend / browser. I get a preprocessed version of the css file wich contains `resources:/` before the font path. I don't want this preprocessing. How can I deactivate it? I think it's the resources plugin which does this.

I'm using Grails 2.2.

CSS:

```
@font-face{
font-family:'FontAwesome'; 
src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal }
```

Output:

```
@font-face{
font-family:'FontAwesome'; 
src:url('resource:/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
src:url('resource:/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('resource:/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
url('resource:/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal }
```

I want to exclude only one css file from the preprocessing. Not all css files.

Comment: What happens if you don't declare the css as a Resource and manually link that on the gsp?